# Searching for arabic words

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have an issue in searching in laravel with arabic words if i have two words like [عماره,عمارة] the difference between them is last letter ه and ة in the normal method for search by using " LIKE " and i wrote عماره it come with the same word not the two words how to handle it and get the two words ?

Comment: Where are you searching? In the database? What collation do you use?

Comment: In database and i use the regular method to search like " $items = Item::where('name','LIKE','%'.$text.'%')->get ()